# Web Crawling in R using Rcrawler

Tags: r

I am trying to get speeches that are specified in links with title on the page "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speeches.htm".

For example, the first title on the page is "Spontaneity and Order: Transparency, Accountability, and Fairness in Bank Supervision" if one clicks on it, it leads the respective speech.

Can someone please let me know how to download all these speeches with titles and dates using Rcrawler?

Thanks
Jalaj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a lot to cover in one question, but it's a fun problem, so I thought I'd take a crack at it anyway. Here's where that led.

**Tidyverse/rvest Version**

First I'm going to build this scraper in the Tidyverse because I'm familiar with using it for web-scraping. So, we'll start by loading the requisite packages.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
```

One challenging aspect of this problem is that there is no single page containing links to all the pages with the speeches. If we scrape links from the main page, however, we find that there is a set of links to pages with all the speeches from any one year. To be clear, I didn't see these links on the main page. Instead, I discovered them by scraping the main page; looking at nodes of type "a" with `html_nodes("a")` because an inspection in Chrome told me that's where relevant links were found; pulling the urls from those results with `html_attr("href")`, and then eyeballing the results in the console to see what looked useful. In those results, I saw links with the forms `"newsevents/speech2020-speeches.htm"` and `"newsevents/speech2007speeches.htm"`, and when I ran the same process over those links, I saw I was getting links to individual speeches. So:

```
# scrape the main page
base_page <- read_html("https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speeches.htm")

# extract links to those annual archives from the resulting html
year_links <- base_page %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  # the pattern for those annual pages changes, so we can use this approach to get both types
  map(c("/newsevents/speech/[0-9]{4}-speeches.htm", "/newsevents/speech/[0-9]{4}speech.htm"), str_subset, string = .) %>%
  reduce(union)

# here's what that produces
> year_links
 [1] "/newsevents/speech/2020-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2019-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2018-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2017-speeches.htm"
 [5] "/newsevents/speech/2016-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2015-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2014-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2013-speeches.htm"
 [9] "/newsevents/speech/2012-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2011-speeches.htm" "/newsevents/speech/2010speech.htm"    "/newsevents/speech/2009speech.htm"   
[13] "/newsevents/speech/2008speech.htm"    "/newsevents/speech/2007speech.htm"    "/newsevents/speech/2006speech.htm"
```

Okay, now we're going to scrape those annual pages for links to the pages for the individual speeches, using `map` to iterate a process over the individual links.

```
speech_links <- map(year_links, function(x) {

  # the scraped links are incomplete, so we'll start by adding the missing bit
  full_url <- paste0("https://www.federalreserve.gov", x)

  # now we'll essentially rerun the process we ran on the main page, only now we can
  # focus on a single string pattern, which again I found by trial and error (i.e.,
  # scrape the page, look at the hrefs on it, see which ones look relevant, check
  # one out in my browser to confirm, then use str_subset() to get ones matching that pattern
  speech_urls <- read_html(full_url) %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    str_subset(., "/newsevents/speech/")

  # add the header now
  return(paste0("https://www.federalreserve.gov", speech_urls))

})

# unlist the results so we have one long vector of links to speeches instead of a list
# of vectors of links
speech_links <- unlist(speech_links)

# here's what the results of that process look like
> head(speech_links)
[1] "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/quarles20200117a.htm"  "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/bowman20200116a.htm"  
[3] "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/clarida20200109a.htm"  "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/brainard20200108a.htm"
[5] "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/brainard20191218a.htm" "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/brainard20191126a.htm"
```

Now, finally, we're going to iterate a scraping process over the pages for the individual speeches to make a tibble with the key elements for each speech: date, title, speaker, location, and full text. I found the node types for each of the desired elements by opening a page for one of the speeches in my Chrome browser, right-clicking (I'm on a Windows machine), and using "Inspect" to see the html associated with the various bits.

```
speech_list <- map(speech_links, function(x) {

  Z <- read_html(x)

  # scrape the date and convert it to 'date' class while we're at it
  date <- Z %>% html_nodes("p.article__time") %>% html_text() %>% as.Date(., format = "%B %d, %Y")

  title <- Z %>% html_nodes("h3.title") %>% html_text()

  speaker <- Z %>% html_nodes("p.speaker") %>% html_text()

  location <- Z %>% html_nodes("p.location") %>% html_text()

  # this one's a little more involved because the text at that node had two elements, 
  # of which we only wanted the second, and I went ahead and cleaned up the speech 
  # text a bit here to make the resulting column easy to work with later
  text <- Z %>%
    html_nodes("div.col-xs-12.col-sm-8.col-md-8") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    .[2] %>%
    str_replace_all(., "\n", "") %>%
    str_trim(., side = "both")

  return(tibble(date, title, speaker, location, text))

})

# finally, bind the one-row elements of that list into a single tibble
speech_table <- bind_rows(speech_list)
```

Here's a glimpse at what that produces, covering 804 Fed speeches from 2006 to the present:

```
> str(speech_table)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       804 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date    : Date, format: "2020-01-17" "2020-01-16" "2020-01-09" "2020-01-08" ...
 $ title   : chr  "Spontaneity and Order: Transparency, Accountability, and Fairness in Bank Supervision" "The Outlook for Housing" "U.S. Economic Outlook and Monetary Policy" "Strengthening the Community Reinvestment Act by Staying True to Its Core Purpose" ...
 $ speaker : chr  "Vice Chair for Supervision Randal K. Quarles" "Governor Michelle W. Bowman" "Vice Chair Richard H. Clarida" "Governor Lael Brainard" ...
 $ location: chr  "At the American Bar Association Banking Law Committee Meeting 2020, Washington, D.C." "At the 2020 Economic Forecast Breakfast, Home Builders Association of Greater Kansas City, Kansas City, Missouri" "At the C. Peter McColough Series on International Economics, Council on Foreign Relations, New York, New York" "At the Urban Institute, Washington, D.C." ...
 $ text    : chr  "It's a great pleasure to be with you today at the ABA Banking Law Committee's annual meeting. I left the practi"| __truncated__ "Few sectors are as central to the success of our economy and the lives of American families as housing. If we i"| __truncated__ "Thank you for the opportunity to join you bright and early on this January 2020 Thursday morning. As some of yo"| __truncated__ "Good morning. I am pleased to be here at the Urban Institute to discuss how to strengthen the Community Reinves"| __truncated__ ...
```

**Rcrawler Version**

Now, you specifically asked about doing this with the `Rcrawler` package, not `rvest`, so here's a solution using the former.

We'll start by using `Rcrawler`'s `LinkExtractor` function with a regular expression to scrape the urls for the pages with links to speeches by year. Note that I only knew what to look for in the regex because I'd already poked through the html to get the `rvest` solution.

```
library(Rcrawler)

year_links = LinkExtractor("https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speeches.htm",
  urlregexfilter = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/")
```

Now we can use `lapply` to iterate `LinkExtractor` over the results of that process to scrape yearly batches of links to the individual speeches. Again, we'll use a regex to focus our scraping, and we only know what pattern to use in the regex because we've eyeballed the results of the previous step and looked at some of those pages in a browser.

```
speech_links <- lapply(year_links$InternalLinks, function(i) {

   linkset <- LinkExtractor(i, urlregexfilter = "speech/[a-z]{1,}[0-9]{8}a.htm")

   # might as well limit the results to the vector of interest while we're here
   return(linkset$InternalLinks)

})

# that process returns a list of vectors, so let's collapse that list into one
# long vector of urls for pages with individual speeches
speech_links <- unlist(speech_links)
```

Finally, we can apply the `ContentScraper` function to the resulting vector of links to individual speeches to extract the data. Inspection of the html for one of those pages revealed the CSS patterns associated with the bits of interest, so we'll use `CssPatterns` to grab those bits and `PatternsName` to give them nice names. That call returns a list of lists of data, so we'll finish up by converting that list of lists to a single data frame using `do.call(rbind.data.frame, ...)` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to avoid converting everything to factors.

```
DATA <- ContentScraper(Url = speech_links,
                       CssPatterns = c(".article__time", ".location", ".speaker", ".title", ".col-xs-12.col-sm-8.col-md-8"),
                       PatternsName = c("date", "location", "speaker", "title", "text"),
                       # we need this next line to get both elements for the .col-xs-12.col-sm-8.col-md-8
                       # bit, which is the text of the speech itself. the first element
                       # is just a repeat of the header info
                       ManyPerPattern = TRUE)

# because the text element is a vector of two strings, we'll want to flatten the
# results into a one-row data frame to make the final concatenation easier. this
# gives us a row with two cols for text, text1 and text2, where text2 is the part
# you really want
DATA2 <- lapply(DATA, function(i) { data.frame(as.list(unlist(i)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) })

# finally, collapse those one-row data frames into one big data frame, one row per speech
output <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(DATA2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Three things to note here: 1) this table only has 779 rows, while the one we got with `rvest` had 806, and I don't know why there is a discrepancy; 2) the data in this table is still raw and could use some cleaning (e.g., convert date strings to class `date`, tidy up the strings in the text column), which you could do with `sapply`; and 3) you'll probably want to drop the superfluous `text1` column, which you could do in base R with `output$text1 <- NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

From the webpage, you can see that all the links and information are contained within a json at the webpage. It might be easier to extract it directly from the json rather than rendering the webpage and then try to extract its content:
https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/ne-speeches.json

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

json <- GET("https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/ne-speeches.json")

speeches <- content(json) %>% # json from the webpage contains urls to speeches
  bind_rows() %>%
  transmute(Name = t,
            url = str_replace(l, "//", "/"), # trying to get rid of the "//" at the beginning of the url
            url = paste0("https://www.federalreserve.gov/", url)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Name)) # filtering NA as the last row of the json is not a valid speech

speeches$speech_transcript <- "" # making sure the column speech_transcript works before I try to assign its values in the loop

for (i in 1:nrow(speeches)) { # going through urls and getting the text of the speeches
  speeches[i,]$speech_transcript <- read_html(speeches[i,]$url) %>%
    html_node("#content") %>%
    html_node("#article") %>%
    html_node("div:nth-child(3)") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_squish() # getting rid of multiple spaces etc.
print(i)
}
```

Comment: I just ran that code, and it looks like the resulting table includes lots of metadata about each speech but not the text of the speech itself. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: The text of the speech has to be accessed using the link. I have uploaded the code to show how to do it.

Comment: I got this error message when I tried to run the code that produces `speeches` without the `head(10)` line: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404. In addition: Warning message: JSON string contains (illegal) UTF8 byte-order-mark!`.

Comment: Yeah, there was a problem with the last speech in that json that was not an actual speech. I have updated the fixed code.

Comment: Yup, that works. Will upvote in a sec. May I suggest that you add comments to your code to explain some of the non-obvious elements (e.g., why the `filter(!is.na(Name))` line is there, what you're doing with `speeches$speech_transcript <- ""`, etc.)?

Comment: I tried to add some comments to make the code easier to understand. Thanks for the suggestion.